# How to send a HTTP request in JMeter which is having an environment in its url?

Tags: jmeter

I want to send HTTP request to a particular URL in JMeter to do performance testing, but the URL is containing a environment name in its prefix **ex:** *http://dev-www.abc.com/*.  while I'm running the particular script its failing because of the URL prefix.

How to achieve this?

Comment: what's not working in that case? How did you define your HTTP request and what's the failure?

Answer (score 0):

If you are enter server name / IP as per screenshot below then it is wrong
[image]

Protocol and server name have to be given separately as below
[image]

If you already have setup URL like the screenshot above, please update the question with screenshot of failure message

Answer (score 0):

Your question is not very clear, going forward consider adding:

- output of the [View Results Tree](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#View_Results_Tree) listener showing request and response tab, preferably both data and [headers](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers)
- jmeter.log file, preferably full, or at least any messages of `WARN` and above [severity](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/log4j/log4j_logging_levels.htm)

A couple of "blind shot" answers:

1. If you're asking for a single configuration point which will be applied to all HTTP Request samplers - it's [HTTP Request Defaults](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/why-its-so-important-use-jmeters-http-request-defaults)
2. If you're building your request URL dynamically and getting `Illegal character found in host: '/'` error - make sure to put the URL into "Path" field of the HTTP Request sampler:

   [image]